# Subtract two vectors with numpy to form a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to do a subtraction of two vectors with numpy, while having the output as a Pandas dataframe
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRIzp.png)

while it worked well with the outer function, it returns the product of the vectors (see image), I couldn't make it work with subtract(), as it returned all values as NaN

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use broadcasting:

```
a = np.array([10,20,30])
b = np.array([1,2,3])

out = a-b[:,None]
```

Or [`numpy.subtract.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), but note that the shape is inverted compared to `np.outer`:

```
np.subtract.outer(a, b).T
```

Output:

```
array([[ 9, 19, 29],
       [ 8, 18, 28],
       [ 7, 17, 27]])
```